# Search for a flight with a layover in a specific place

Tags: air-travel, layovers, flight-search-engines, connecting-flights

I was looking on skyscanner and kayak one week ago for flights.

I want to go from **Buenos Aires** to **El Calafate** around 8 January 2019 (+-2 days) and come back around 12 January (+-2days).

Usually the flights cost around 150 EUR which I would say it's a decent price. The problem is that now I find only direct flights.

I know, sounds weird that I don't like this. But last week I was getting a lot of result having a pretty long layover (more than 10h) in Ushuaia, the price was similar.

I would like to spend half a day(or maximum a full day) in Ushuaia too.

But I don't find any flights with a layover there anymore.

Is it possible to search for a flight from A to B with a connection in C?
(in this case from Buenos Aires to El Calafate with a long layover in Ushuaia)

---

I was trying multicity Buenos Aires - El Calafate, El Calafate-Ushuaia, Ushuaia-Buenos Aires but I was getting only fares about 450 EUR

Answer (score 1):

http://matrix.itasoftware.com/ can do this. Hit advanced controls and type in USH. In October the lowest fare for AEP->USH->FTE was about 135 Euro. You can also specify a minimum connection time to make sure you have enough time in USH.

You can't book directly on ITA but you can go through 3rd party sites or directly through the airline using the info from ITA

Comment: On that website it is pretty cheap. But as you said, it cannot be bought from there and when I'm going to kayak or skyscanner and enter a multi city travel to return me that flights the total cost exceeds 300 EUR